# Unable to access NodeJS model class from the controller. Using EJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Please, am just started learning node.js and using some online resources and need some help. I am following a shopping project with Cart. The setup uses the MVC pattern. I need to get the product.price to populate the cart. But getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined.

Please find below the codes.

1. The model:
   **product.js**

```
    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');    
    const p = path.join(
    path.dirname(require.main.filename),'data','products.json');
    
    const getProductsFromFile = cb => {
      fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
        if (err) {
          cb([]);
        } else {
          cb(JSON.parse(fileContent));
        }
      });
    };
    
    module.exports = class Product {
      constructor(title, imageUrl, description, price) {
        this.title = title;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        this.description = description;
        this.price = price;
      }
    
      save() {
        this.id = Math.random().toString();
        getProductsFromFile(products => {
          products.push(this);
          fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(products), err => {
            console.log(err);
          });
        });
      }
    
      static fetchAll(cb) {
        getProductsFromFile(cb);
      }
    
      static findById(id, cb){
        getProductsFromFile(products => {
          const product = products.find(p => p.id === id);
          cb(product);
        });
      }
    };
```

**cart.js**

```
         const fs = require('fs');
         const path = require('path');
        
            const p = path.join(
              path.dirname(require.main.filename),
              'data',
              'cart.json'
            );
            
            module.exports = class Cart {
              static addProduct(id, productPrice) {
                // Fetch the previous cart
                console.log(p)
                fs.readFile(p, (err, fileContent) => {
                  let cart = { products: [], totalPrice: 0 };
                  if (!err) {
                    cart = JSON.parse(fileContent);
                  }
                  // Analyze the cart => Find existing product
                  const existingProductIndex = cart.products.findIndex(prod => prod.id === id);
                  const existingProduct = cart.products[existingProductIndex];
                  let updatedProduct;
                  // Add new product/ increase quantity
                  if (existingProduct) {
                    updatedProduct = { ...existingProduct };
                    updatedProduct.qty = updatedProduct.qty + 1;
                    cart.products = [...cart.products];
                    cart.products[existingProductIndex] = updatedProduct;
                  } else {
                    updatedProduct = { id: id, qty: 1 };
                    cart.products = [...cart.products, updatedProduct];
                  }
                  cart.totalPrice = cart.totalPrice + +productPrice;
                  fs.writeFile(p, JSON.stringify(cart), err => {
                    console.log(err);
                  });
                });
              }
            };
```

shop.js - The Controller

```
    
    const Product = require('../models/product');
    const Cart = require('../models/cart');
    
    exports.postCart = (req, res, next) => {
      const prodId = req.body.productId;
      Product.findById(prodId, product => {
          //console.log(product);
        Cart.addProduct(prodId, product.price);
      });
      res.redirect('/cart');
    };
```

Can't get the product.price because the product value is null.
Any assistance will be highly appreciated. Following the tutorial, the product instance was created but **unable to figure out why the product is still undefined.**

Comment: Show your `prodId ` value, and make sure that the id is existing in the json file.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I am able to write to the cart.json file, if I replace the product.price with a value like 20. I am just unable to find out why the product object is not been returned. Here is the content of the cart.jason file after putting in a value instead of dynamically getting it from the product object.     {"products":[{"id":"0.6767204660230142 ","qty":1}],"totalPrice":20.2}